# Laravel morph table with morph field id size larger than one

Tags: php, laravel, uuid

I have a personal access token table with the following structure:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->morphs('tokenable');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
        $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Now, this worked fine when I had an auto-incrementing integer as my user id that will be storing access tokens in this table, but I have changed my User ids to uuids instead. Now, I get the following error in when the *personal_access_tokens* is being created due to the *tokenable_id* not being able to store a uuid (I think)

```
"SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'tokenable_id' at row 1 
(SQL: insert into `personal_access_tokens` (`name`, `token`, `abilities`, 
    `tokenable_id`, `tokenable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (my-token, 
     ef16e51c374d0a2dddf029b29f59ae62eb518c64f2f19945f7adc2cd67548ca7, [\"*\"], 
     96481014-efb0-42ce-9037-1f256c074976, App\\User, 
     2020-05-15 21:08:39, 2020-05-15 21:08:39))",
```

Any idea how I can change the tokenable_id field to accept uuids instead?

Comment: I just found `$table->uuidMorphs('taggable');` adds `taggable_id` CHAR(36) and `taggable_type` VARCHAR(255) UUID equivalent columns. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-columns. Maybe it's what you're looking for

Comment: Exaclty what I'm looking for! I've already manually added the morph fields, but this will come in handy in the future. Make it an answer so that I can tag correct.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the data type of the columns must match, and the primary key of your `User` model has the `uuid` format, the `morphs()` method will not work for you in this case. You can create the columns manually, as you indicate in the comments, but (since laravel version 5.8) the `uuidMorphs()` method is also available.

[Creating Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-columns)
**Available Column Types**

---

```
$table->morphs('taggable');
```

Adds `taggable_id` *UNSIGNED BIGINT* and `taggable_type` *VARCHAR* equivalent columns.

---

```
$table->uuidMorphs('taggable');
```

Adds `taggable_id` *CHAR(36)* and `taggable_type` *VARCHAR(255) UUID* equivalent columns.

---

Comment: This help to decide to just replace morphs for bigInteger and string with fixed size.

Comment: uuidMorphs didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is the correct answer, I would like to add, you can also use

```
            $table->ulidMorphs('taggable');
```

for those who use ulid ids instead of uuid,